# app inventor. Application communication via WI-FI

Tags: web, app-inventor

Good afternoon. Please help in creating the application.
A project is being created to control the air suspension of the car through Arduino. The application is written in App Inventor. The connection must be established via Wi-Fi. 
Q: how do I do this in App Inventor? What are the blocks? So that when you start the application, it is immediately connected to Wi-Fi.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to S.O.! You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to find out how to ask for help on this site. As of now, your question is way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary to auto-connect your Android device to WiFi. The connection over WiFi method is much user-friendly to connect it manually. But, if you intent to do this, you could use [TaifunWiFi](https://puravidaapps.com/wifi.php).

hope this help.